# SSLの設定をした後nginxが起動できない

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

プログラミング、開発環境構築の初心者です。

Ubuntu,nginx,gunicorn,DjangoでPythonのwebシステムを開発しています。

ローカルで作ったサイトを、Ubuntu,ncinx,gunicorn,Djangoを使用したサーバーにデプロイし、独自ドメインでのアクセスが可能な状況まで開発しました。
その後、SSL化に対応させるために、Let's Encryptを利用してnginxのファイルを設定しているのですが、ファイルの編集を行った後、nginxが起動できない状況です。

解決策について、ご教授していただきないでしょうか？

**エラーログ**

```
* nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-12-09 10:20:34 JST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 1882 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 nginx[1882]: nginx: [warn] the "ssl" directive is deprecated, use the "listen ... ssl" directive instead in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myblogapp:47
Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 nginx[1882]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No s
Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 nginx[1882]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

**nginx設定ファイル**

```
#httpリダイレクト
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name harvest-timer.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

#wwwリダイレクト
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.harvest-timer.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/privkey.pem;
    return 301 https://harvest-timer.com$request_uri;
}

#リダイレクト先設定
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name harvest-timer.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/harvest-timer.com/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico {access_log off; log_not_found off;}

    location /static/ {
                alias /home/username/myblogapp;
    }

    location /static/admin {
                alias /home/username/dj2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin;
    }

    location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/myblogapp/myblogapp.sock;
    }

}
                                                                                                                                                    75,1          Bot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージ「Dec 09 10:20:34 ik1-305-12685 nginx[1882]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No s」[直訳]（証明書　"/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem"が読み込めません）の対処を最初にすべきだと思います。証明書が無ければSSLは出来ませんからね。

"/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem"　というファイルは存在しますか？　
nginxが起動されるディレクトリ(cwd)を確認して、その下に"/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.harvest-timer.com/fullchain.pem"があることを確認してみてください。
ファイルのパーミッションの設定のために、読み込めない可能性もあります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。解決できました。www.harvest-timer.com→harvest-timer.comが正解でした。